# WCF Cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

When i try use a webservice i get the following exception. My main question is when does this exception happen? on the server or client? where is the error? Does the server throw this for a wide range of faults?

**I did some changes on my own that seems to work**

It actually works now. I removed using and added som cleanup on the service client.

```
if (Service != null && Service.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    success = true;
                    Service.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace;
            }
            finally{
                if (!success)
                {
                    if (Service != null) Service.Abort();
                }
            }
```

This was the exception:

```
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Close()
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
at bNet.Services.Customers.Cres.Helios.ServiceForm.Send(ServiceFormAction task) in C:\bNetProjects\bNet Web Tools\Solution root\bNet.Services\Customers\Cres\Helios\ServiceForm.cs:line 99
at bNet.Web.Sites.Public.Customers.Cres.ServiceSkjema.Units.Page.ServiceFormControl.SubmitFormClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\bNetProjects\bNet Web Tools\Solution root\bNet.Web.Sites.Public\Customers\Cres\ServiceSkjema\Units\Page\ServiceFormControl.ascx.cs:line 192
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: The exception call stack in fact tells you a lot that you must pay attention to. For example, Dispose calls Close. Therefore, if the proxy is already in Faulted state, you can only call Abort, not Close nor Dispose. Luckily you find out the necessary change. Microsoft in fact has a nice article that emphasizes on what kind of calling pattern is recommended, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Comment: Take a look here as well  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763592/the-communication-object-system-servicemodel-channels-servicechannel-cannot-be

Comment: Also got exactly this exception not because exception handling, but just for trying to return `DataTable` without `TableName` set. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702/returning-datatables-in-wcf-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763592/the-communication-object-system-servicemodel-channels-servicechannel-cannot-be)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Faulted state means there has been an *unexpected* exception on the server side. In an earlier call.

You should have gotten an exception at the client side too, maybe your code ignores it?

You can solve it by reopening the connection. But it seems you need better error handling.

Comment: I did some changes my self that did the job. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 10):

*Instead* of using the `using` statement, try running your code without it.

From

```
using(var client = new WCFClient())
{
    // ... code
}
```

to

```
var client = new WCFClient()

// ... code
```

Upon doing so, we were able to see that the original **WCF Cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state** message was caused by the `using()` call itself. *Why?* Our code that was using the WCF client was passing in invalid credentials, and the server responded with an error and changing the state of the proxy to faulted. The `using()` block, [as we know](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), calls `Dispose()` on the object - in this case our WCF client.

Because the WCF client failed, and the WCF client was in a faulted state, calling `Dispose()` caused the error **WCF Cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state** to be thrown.

We were able to see this by wrapping the code that uses the WCF client in a `try...catch` block.

Comment: Kudos @Zac, removing using helped us catch the appropriate exception which happened to be:

"The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials.".

Seems removing using should be the first thing to do to get the exact exception than the generic:

"The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."

Comment: Same here. Only after removing the using block could I see more details about the error.

Answer (score 2):

This error can also be caused by having zero methods tagged with the OperationContract attribute. This was my problem when building a new service and testing it a long the way.