# how can i handle WCF Services when database result is very great?

Tags: c#, wcf, state

I use code below:

```
private class WcfProxy<TService> :
            ClientBase<TService> where TService : class, IContract
        {
            public TService WcfChannel
            {
                get
                {
                    return Channel;
                }
            }
        }

    protected TResult ExecuteCommand<TResult>(Func<TContract, TResult> command)
        where TResult : IDtoResponseEnvelop
    {
        var proxy = new WcfProxy<TContract>();

        try
        {
            var result = command.Invoke(proxy.WcfChannel);
            proxy.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ex)
        {
            proxy.Abort();
            throw new BusinessException(BusinessExceptionEnum.Operational, Properties.Resources.Exception.WcfAdapterBase_CommunicationException_TransportInEnamDataIsInvalid, ex);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            proxy.Abort();
            throw new BusinessException(BusinessExceptionEnum.Operational, Properties.Resources.Exception.WcfAdapterBase_TimeoutException, ex);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            proxy.Abort();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When the query returns high amount of result
i encounter with this message:

The communication object cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

does exist a way or trick that i observe the result of database query successfully
or a way that i divide the result or get part of result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably youneed to enlatge maxReceivedMessageSize, or one of other parameters of binding.

You can also enable wcf trace and review it with svcTraceViewer.exe

Comment: i set maxReceivedMessageSize to 2147483647 because if set larger than it i encounter with error

Comment: its right an ok, since this number is Max integer. Think are you really need it so big :)

Answer (score 0):

You get this error:

> The communication object cannot be used for communication because it
>   is in the Faulted state.

because you throw an error and it is not handled and gets thrown in the *iis pool*.

Check this link out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/fc60cd6d-1df9-47ff-90a8-dd8d5de1f080/ also this is not caused by the large ammount of data: [WCF Cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409329/wcf-cannot-be-used-for-communication-because-it-is-in-the-faulted-state)