# WCF Service Not working when try to connect to database

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I created a WCF service to communicate with database, first I created a sample `Helloworld!` method it's working fine

but when I try to call the actual methods it's giving following exception

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://10.11.32.211:87/Service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.

In the browser

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

### My web.config file

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>

<!--<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>-->

<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
       <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="3000" maxConcurrentSessions="3000" maxConcurrentInstances="3000"/>
     </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

I go through these links but it didn't worked
[MSDN LINK1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/3aec066e-5985-4d3e-ae1e-b054597aaa84)

### Edit

Actually what I am doing with this service is to execute a stored procedure on the server

```
using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
            {
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
                return table;
            }
        }
```

I am able to call the same stored procedure from different website manually but not using this service....

What is it? and why this is coming?

Comment: Config for both server and client are needed.  (Just the services part of the graph)

Comment: @MarkM this service is working fine when i try to call a `helloworld` method which will take a string input and returns a string

Comment: @MarkM can you share a link or some code for server and client configuration

Comment: Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and/or enable [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to find out what's going wrong. This can be caused by many things, for example an incorrect query (does it run fine in SSMS?), wrong permissions (is the app pool user allowed to connect?), broken query string (is the database accessible?), too much data (see answer by SliverNinja), or an incorrect binding at the client. Please debug first.

Comment: If you have a service method already working follow CodeCaster's suggestions. Unless you've set up another endpoint for the malfunctioning call it's probably not a configuration issue.

Comment: @MarkM  Hey [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42332/1196411) solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332/1196411), we just need to instantiate the datatable with a specified name in its constructor

like

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
```

I don't know why this gives error but this solved the issue........

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the send or receive timeout and assigning proper readerQuotas for `basicHttpBinding`.

```xml
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding  maxBufferSize="5000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" >
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="80192" maxArrayLength="50000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

Comment: Did you try [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7209823/175679)? This is often a sign of returning too much data. Try reducing the data size to a single record instead of all records from your DB to verify.

Comment: Thanks actually i do have the same problem, just now i checked with the insert sp its working(its storing record in db) but showing error in client side

Comment: Thanks for sharing back your solution (*giving the `DataTable` a name*)!