# WCF CommunicationException

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I am using WCF service in a web application. Two services are and one method `which returns string`  is there in first and returns a `DataTable` in second
`First one is working properly` while i am calling through the service.
But `while calling second one` i get the following `exception`
[image]

Here is the config in server

> ```
>   <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="RmtUsers.Menu">
>     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IRmtUsers.IMenu">
>       <identity>
>         <dns value="192.168.50.35"/>
>       </identity>
>     </endpoint>
>     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
>   </service>
>
>   <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="RmtUsers.Product">
>     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IRmtUsers.IProduct">
>       <identity>
>         <dns value="192.168.50.35"/>
>       </identity>
>     </endpoint>
>     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
>   </service>
>           </services>
>       <behaviors>             <serviceBehaviors>
>           <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
>               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
>               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
>           </behavior>             </serviceBehaviors>         </behaviors>    </system.serviceModel>
> ```

In the client

> ```
>  <bindings>
>   <wsHttpBinding>
>     <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMenu" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
>       receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
>       transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
>       maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
>       textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
>       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
>         maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
>       <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
>         enabled="false" />
>       <security mode="Message">
>         <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
>           realm="" />
>         <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
>           algorithmSuite="Default" />
>       </security>
>     </binding>
>     <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IProduct" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
>       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
>     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="falsehostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
>       maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
>       textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
>       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
>         maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
>       <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
>         enabled="false" />
>       <security mode="Message">
>         <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
>           realm="" />
>         <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
>           algorithmSuite="Default" />
>       </security>
>     </binding>
> ```

Comment: You're probably getting an error when WCF tries to serialize the DataTable - use a DataSet again (if you must you built-in .NET Types).  The exception you'r seeing could be caused by any number of things, and in this case it's probably because the service enters a faulted state (due to the serialization error) and then times out.

Answer (score 1):

Try following.

1 - Use SvcTraceViewer utility to trace the cause of the issue.
2 - Give some name to the datatable that you are returning from WCF like this.

```
new DataTable("someName");
```

WCF: DataTable was not initialized with a name. Note sure why..

Comment: I had a similar issue and again all I needed was to name my `DataTable`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the following code. Now its working fine

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable("products");
     dt= getData();  
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);
     return ds.Tables[0];
```

I got this ans from [Jani5e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702/net-returning-datatables-in-wcf)

Comment: See my comment above - based on my experiences, the DataTable won't serialize, but a DataSet will.